# Curved Grid Layout Group

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I can't find a quick answer anywhere, besides adding a 100 line script that I'm pretty sure is outdated. As the title suggests, I am trying to curve a grid layout group. I also want the children of the object with the grid component to rotate according to where it is. Thanks in advance. I'm trying to do this in 2D, in UI, if that helps. I'm also in the latest version of unity.

I want the objects to be on the line (without the actual line) with rotating depending on where it is.

[image]

(if you're wondering I did try the script and I'm pretty sure it's unity-script)

Comment: Can you show an image of what rotation you want? There are many ways to rotate objects to make a curve, so we'll need to be sure we're matching the one you actually want. Did you try that 100 line script to test whether it still works, or check what specific error it reports?

Comment: Just edited the question to show the things you requested.

Comment: A grid layout group has multiple rows of items. Do you want multiple rows arranged like concentric bands of a rainbow? Or do you want just one row of items, more like a horizontal layout group?

Comment: I just want one row of items.

Comment: Try this UI Extensions Radial Layout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUlk0d2RDMs&t=138s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UI Extensions -> RadialLayout script:
https://github.com/Unity-UI-Extensions/com.unity.uiextensions

And there is the video how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUlk0d2RDMs&t=138s